# LINQ CosmosDB MongoDB API upsert E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have just started to try out cosmosdb with the mongodb api and my application is quite easy. It listens on a message queue and store that data in the database. This data might already be stored and needs to get updated so I do an upsert.

The problem is that on the update it fails with a duplicate key error. I have tried to read a bit about this but haven't found any documentation. What I did find out is that you shouldn't set the id when doing the update which I find hard to do.

This is the code I have:

```
await Ctx.ReplaceOneAsync(d => d.Id == importedData.Id, importedData, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

And this is the error I get:

```
A write operation resulted in an error.
E11000 duplicate key error collection: test Failed _id or unique key constraint A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors.
```

How do I do an update based on the id when using linq?